# Where are composer packages installed?

Tags: xampp, composer-php

My guide: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer

It says `Make sure you have ~/.composer/vendor/bin/ in your path.`

On a Win7 machine, where would that be?

I assume it is my php project folders, because the `vendor` folder appears after a `composer install`

But every package has it's own bin folder... am I supposed to update my path everytime I add a package? This can't be right.

UPDATE:
After configuring composer to install phpunit, phpcs, phploc, pdepend, phpmd, phpcpd, and phpdox I get this:

```
.\project\vendor\bin
.\project\vendor\composer
.\project\vendor\nikic
.\project\vendor\phpunit
.\project\vendor\theseer
.\project\vendor\zetacompnents
```

`.\project\vendor\bin` contains `phpdox` and `phpdox.bat` only.

**UPDATE:**
After a bit of help on other issues with Composer, I realise the problem here is that composer is uninstalling packages from vendor/bin - unexpectedly.

As soon as I add `"squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.0.0a2"` to my composer.json, then I get this when I `composer update`

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing phpmd/phpmd (2.0.0)
  - Removing pdepend/pdepend (2.0.0)
```

Why are these packages now removed? I still need them. I'll post this as a new question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Windows users:

The packages are installed where your command line is currently located e.g. C:\Users\user\

Check for C:\Users\user\vendor folder and its contents

use instead of "user" your account name e.g. C:\Users\Maxcot\

Hope this helps Windows users.

Answer (score -1):

Answering your second question: No, if you install packages globally with Composer, there is only one folder `vendor/bin` for "binary files", but it actually depends on whether a given package will utilize this.

If you install development packages in the project (I would recommend doing this with PHPUnit at least, it allows anybody to run the tests without having to deal with installing the correct version), then the `vendor/bin` file is local and can be accessed via a relative path, so there shouldn't be a difference between platforms.

The only thing I cannot answer right now is where Windows puts the `.composer` folder, because I have only ever used Composer on Linux.

Comment: :) given my frustrations lately trying to get this working, a wholesale conversion to linux is looking very attractive.

Comment: OK, so I can access the vendor/bin via a relative path. But the other tools do not sit in the bin folder, so then I have to manually put the phar files into the bin directory.... so why use composer?  The guide in the link says `We assume that these tools are on the $PATH and can be invoked with phpunit, phpcs, phploc, pdepend, phpmd, phpcpd, and phpdox, respectively.`

Comment: Which guide? I get it that you are now trying to install all these QA tools via Composer, which is what I'd also suggest. To start them all, you could either use a homemade script or create something with Phing, Ant or so. My approach is to install Phing globally with Composer, enabling the build scripts in a project to be run and taking care of the rest, including that path problem you experience, because every tool that is run can be addressed in a separate task, and you don't have to fiddle with the command line. A simple run of something like `phing qa` would execute all.

Comment: The guide I refer to is at the top of the original post. I just don't understand Composer's role. It downloads various tools, which I can see - they appear in the project folder under `vendor` - but they are all over the place in various subdirectories under that. So if I use Ant or Phing, or anything else for that matter, I'm going to have to write out path to each tool in the script. . Why not just download a PHAR version of each tool and dump them in one directory. No composer required.

Comment: The link goes to the PHPUnit installtion guide. It does not mention any of the other tools and does not contain the quote from your first comment.